# Show any continuous function $f: \mathbb{\bar N} \to (\mathbb{R}, \tau_c)$ is eventually constant

Tags: general-topology

Show any continuous function $f:\mathbb{\bar N} \to (\mathbb{R}, \tau_c)$ is eventually constant.

Preliminaries:

$\tau_c = \{U \subset \mathbb{R} \mid U = \emptyset \vee U^c : \text{countable}    \}$ the cocountable topology

$\mathbb{\bar N} = \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$

Let $f:\mathbb{\bar N} \to (\mathbb{R}, \tau_c)$ be a continuous mapping.

From characterizations of continuity : $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open then $f^{-1}(U) \subset \mathbb{\bar N}$ is open.

$\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff so disjoint open sets exist so it seems eventually the preimage of two open sets in the codomain will no longer have an empty intersection.

I am just not sure how to show this exactly. Like how do I know which $U,V \subset \mathbb{R}$ : open to use. Seems that cocountable is the key for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\langle\Bbb R,\tau_c\rangle$ is *not* Hausdorff. In fact, *no* two points of $\Bbb R$ have disjoint open nbhds in the that topology.

HINT: Let $a=f(\infty)$. Show that

$$U=\Bbb R\setminus\{f(n):n\in\Bbb N\text{ and }f(n)\ne a\}$$

is an open nbhd of $a$. What condition must $f$ satisfy in order for $U$ to contain $f(n)$ for all sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: Oh, it's Hausdorff under the usual toplogy but not this one, okay that makes some sense. I think I understand: $F$ is continuous by assumption so we are assuming it is continuous for all inputs "all the way to $\infty$ " that poor wording but I think the idea is clear. so $U$ has to either empty or it has to have a countable complement since for sufficiently large $N$ we end up in a scenario that $\forall n \ge N, f(n) \in U$ i.e. beyond a certain point it becomes cocountable. So for $U$ to contain all $f(n)$ for sufficiently large $N$ is must be monotone. I think I am getting closer.

Comment: @oliverjones: Slow down a bit. The set $U$ that I defined is co-countable no matter what $f$ is, and it contains $a$, so it’s definitely an open nbhd of $a$. In order for $f$ to be continuous, there must be an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(n)\in U$ for all $n\ge m$. What must $f(n)$ be in order to belong to $U$?

Comment: It's like sequences right? $f(n), n\ge m$ is like a limit point, or it converges to $f(n)$ for all $n \ge m$ so we get an infinitely many becoming cocountable so it has to be eventually constant. How do I word that without using sequences though.

Comment: @oliverjones: It’s *very* closely related to sequences: the sequence $\langle f(n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $f(\infty)$ if and only if $f$ is continuous. But you don’t have to talk about sequences. You just need to know that $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $\overline{\Bbb N}$. Since $\infty\in f^{-1}[U]$, you need to show that $f^{-1}[U]$ contains an open nbhd of $\infty$ in $\overline{\Bbb N}$. What do the open nbhds of $\infty$ look like?

Comment: The open nbhds of $\infty $ in $\overline{ \Bbb N}$ are all cofinite subsets of $\overline{\Bbb N}$

Comment: @oliverjones: Right, which means that they are precisely the sets $V$ with the property that there is some $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $$V\supseteq\{n\in\Bbb N:n\ge m\}\;:$$ any natural numbers *not* in $V$ must be among the finitely many that are less than $m$.